# Using Past perfect with till

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, past-perfect

> He did not wait till we had finished our meal.

Why this construction is grammatically correct?

I mean (and feel) *He did not wait* is first event, *finished* is second.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you think should be wrong with this sentence?

Comment: I think right way is   
He had not waited till we finished our meal.

Comment: That means something completely different.

Comment: "He did not wait until we had finished our meal, but rushed into the dining-room while we were eating" is perfectly acceptable. If you were describing the situation after the meal, you could say "My father was angry that he had not waited until we [had] finished our meal."

Comment: I think my problem is perceiving of the "finished" verb. In my mind this is end of eating.